# URL shortener policy

Tags: discussion, code-golf, rules

I haven't seen a discussion on this yet, but I also haven't really seen it *used* in answers, so I figured it was worth asking a question for link-reference in the future.

So, what's the policy on using URL shortening services to reduce characters for golfs? [This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25258/14215) made me think of it. Answers could easily save a bunch of characters, from something like:

> https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/-1?tab=activity&sort=revisions

to:

> http://goo.gl/QKvsEZ

I can't point to anything technically wrong with it, but it just feels so... **cheap**.

If there's no policy yet, what *should* it be?

Comment: [URL shorteners are now a standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/10166#10166)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have been used in answers in the past: see e.g.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acodegolf.stackexchange.com+inurl:questions+tinyurl
- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acodegolf.stackexchange.com+inurl:questions+goo.gl
- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acodegolf.stackexchange.com+inurl:questions+t.co

There aren't many questions which will generate answers which legitimately include hard-coded URLs. (Some of those previous answers would now fall foul of [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/194)). For the exceptions, I would say that the problem is probably in the question rather than the answers. If hard-coded URLs are useful and not loopholes then that strongly implies that the question isn't taking input, which is a "question smell".

Comment: It may also mean the question itself involves connecting to a web site, like [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25146/3681).

Comment: @celtschk, that's a prime example of my last sentence. It could easily be generalised to take the domain of a StackExchange network site as a parameter, and then it wouldn't be able to use a URL minifier.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in questions which require you to access a certain webpage, you should be allowed to access *that webpage only*, because we don't allow external resources *unless stated otherwise*.

A URL shortener is an external resource (it stores the URL of the page it redirects to), so **like all external resources it should be banned unless the question explicitly says so**.